# JS get varible defined in script tag (Google Extension)

Tags: javascript, html, object, dom, google-chrome-extension

I've got a small problem. I want to read a var defined inside  tag in DOM.

```
<script id="foo">
    var x = 1
</script>
```

I can access it via:

```
var script = document.querySelector("#foo");
```

But then what? Of course

```
var x_value = script.x
```

or

```
var x_value = script.outerHTML.x
```

doesn't work. So how can I get x's value then?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can get the content of the tag, pass it to a JavaScript parser and traverse the AST to find what you want. However, that will of course not work if the value is computed dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content script runs in [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) so it cannot access the page variables directly.

- a literal numeric value can be extracted with a regexp:

  ```
  var scriptText = document.getElementById('foo').textContent;
  var x = parseFloat(scriptText.match(/var x\s*=\s*(-?(\d*\.)?\d+(e-?\d+)?)|$/)[1]);
  ```
- a global page variable of any JSON-ifiable type [can be accessed from a `script` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) because it runs in page context:

  ```
  function getPageVariable(name) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      window.addEventListener(`${chrome.runtime.id}-variable`, e => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(e.detail));
      }, {once: true});
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      document.documentElement.appendChild(script).text = `
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('${chrome.runtime.id}-variable', {
          detail: JSON.stringify(window.${name})
        }))`;
      script.remove();
    });
  }
  ```

  Usage:

  ```
  getPageVariable('x').then(x => {
    // do something with x
  });
  ```

  Depending on the page CSP, a [different method of code injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) may be required.

Comment: I was hoping I could extract it from window object, something like `window.x`, but idk where that var is stored, it has to be somewhere though.

Comment: But it seems the second option works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Once you're within the scope you should be able to access your variable from wherever you want...

```
<script id="foo">
    var x = 1
</script>
<div id="test">
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```